# If A is dependent upon B, is B necessarily dependent upon A?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I read that independence of two events has a symmetric relationship. Does this relationship hold for dependent events as well?

If so, what would be the intuition?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, two events are dependent if and only if they are not independent. 
Since, if $\mu$ is a probability measure, then events A and B are independent if and only if
\begin{equation}
\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A)\cdot\mu(B)
\end{equation}
and dependent otherwise.  Since multiplication is commutative you easily get exactly what you're looking for.

An easy example is a double coin toss: intuitively the result of tossing the first coin should have no effect on the second and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks, any recommendation on becoming more familiar with this stuff? I'm currently taking a class at a University that is covering this content a bit too fast for my liking.

Comment: I'm a big fan of the MIT open courseware and would thus recommend taking a peek at that and the books they used.  This also depends on the flavour of probility you are doing.  For a more statistical/applied approach (or to find the intuiton/motivation behind theory) you can check out [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/index.htm).  For a more mathematical (measure-theoretic) approach have a look at say [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-175-theory-of-probability-spring-2014/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The language $A$ dependent on $B$ is a bit vague, since it may involve something wherein there is a causal dependency that $A$ happens because $B$ does. Stochastic independence avoids that: Events $A,B$ are independent iff $P(A \land B)=P(A)P(B).$ So $A,B$ are dependent iff $P(A \land B)\neq P(A)P(B),$ and the latter is symmetric in $A,B.$ I don't know what rules one uses in case "A depends on B" means something other than stochastic dependence.